# Perl XML::Simple parser decoding inconsistency

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

I have encountered an "inconsistency" (for me) while parsing XML:

```
use 5.14.2;
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $xml;
{local $/;
$xml = <DATA>;}

my $xmlParsed = XMLin($xml,
            KeyAttr => {phone => 'type', tankstelle => 'id'},
            ForceArray => [ 'phone' ],
                        ContentKey => '-content',
                       );
say Dumper($$xmlParsed{'tankstelle'});


__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tankstellen>
    <tankstelle>
        <id>63</id>
        <phone type="main">0911 731586</phone>
        <phone type="fax">0911 7592228</phone>
        <number/>
    </tankstelle>
    <tankstelle>
        <id>64</id>
        <phone type="main">0911 732011</phone>
        <phone type="fax"></phone>
        <number>64</number>
    </tankstelle>
    <tankstelle>
        <id>91</id>
        <phone type="main">0911 732926</phone>
        <phone type="fax">0911 732917</phone>
        <number/>
    </tankstelle>
    <tankstelle>
        <id>92</id>
        <phone type="main">0911 737577</phone>
        <phone type="fax"></phone>
        <number/>
    </tankstelle>
</tankstellen>
```

Sometimes number is a hash and sometimes a string.  If type="fax" is empty it main contains content.

I tried different options for the parser to get rid of the hash in main and number without luck.

```
'64' => {
        'number' => '64',
        'phone' => {
                   'main' => {
                             'content' => '0911 732011'
                           },
                   'fax' => {}
                 }
      },
'91' => {
        'phone' => {
                   'fax' => '0911 732917',
                   'main' => '0911 732926'
                 },
        'number' => {}
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sad that [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Simple) is probably the most complicated XML module on CPAN, yet beginners choose it hoping for an easy ride. Its own documentation now says this

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces. In particular, XML::LibXML is highly recommended.

You have seen for yourself how difficult it is to get it to behave properly with anything but the simplest XML, and it has a huge disadvantage in that it treats attributes the same way as elements.

Taking the author's advice, this short program produces something like the data structure that I think you want, with the advantage that you can amend it to create any structure you like from the XML.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;
use Data::Dump;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => \*DATA);

my %data;

for my $ts ($xml->findnodes('/tankstellen/tankstelle')) {

  my $id = $ts->findvalue('id');

  $data{$id}{number} = $ts->findvalue('number');

  for my $phone ($ts->findnodes('phone')) {
    my $type = $phone->findvalue('@type');
    $data{$id}{phone}{$type} = $phone->findvalue('text()');
  }
}

dd \%data;


__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tankstellen>
    <tankstelle>
        <id>63</id>
        <phone type="main">0911 731586</phone>
        <phone type="fax">0911 7592228</phone>
        <number/>
    </tankstelle>
    <tankstelle>
        <id>64</id>
        <phone type="main">0911 732011</phone>
        <phone type="fax"></phone>
        <number>64</number>
    </tankstelle>
    <tankstelle>
        <id>91</id>
        <phone type="main">0911 732926</phone>
        <phone type="fax">0911 732917</phone>
        <number/>
    </tankstelle>
    <tankstelle>
        <id>92</id>
        <phone type="main">0911 737577</phone>
        <phone type="fax"></phone>
        <number/>
    </tankstelle>
</tankstellen>
```

**output**

```
{
  63 => {
          number => "",
          phone  => { fax => "0911 7592228", main => "0911 731586" },
        },
  64 => {
          number => 64,
          phone => { fax => "", main => "0911 732011" }
        },
  91 => {
          number => "",
          phone  => { fax => "0911 732917", main => "0911 732926" },
        },
  92 => {
          number => "",
          phone => { fax => "", main => "0911 737577" }
        },
}
```

Tool completed successfully

Comment: Thank you, I think I have missed this important piece of information in the documentation...

Answer (score 1):

As said before, using XML::LibXML is highly recommended.

However, if (for huge XML documents) memory efficiency is more important than CPU speed, one could consider an alternative: [XML::Reader::PP](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Reader::PP)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Reader::PP;
use Data::Dump;

my $rdr = XML::Reader::PP->new(\*DATA, { mode => 'branches' },
  { root => '/tankstellen/tankstelle', branch => [ 
    'id',
    'phone[@type="main"]',
    'phone[@type="fax"]',
    'number',
  ]});

my %data;

while ($rdr->iterate) {
    my ($id, $ph_main, $ph_fax, $num) = $rdr->value;
    $_ //= '' for ($id, $ph_main, $ph_fax, $num);

    $data{$id}{'number'}        = $num;
    $data{$id}{'phone'}{'main'} = $ph_main;
    $data{$id}{'phone'}{'fax'}  = $ph_fax;
}

dd \%data;

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tankstellen>
    <tankstelle>
        <id>63</id>
        <phone type="main">0911 731586</phone>
        <phone type="fax">0911 7592228</phone>
        <number/>
    </tankstelle>
    <tankstelle>
        <id>64</id>
        <phone type="main">0911 732011</phone>
        <phone type="fax"></phone>
        <number>64</number>
    </tankstelle>
    <tankstelle>
        <id>91</id>
        <phone type="main">0911 732926</phone>
        <phone type="fax">0911 732917</phone>
        <number/>
    </tankstelle>
    <tankstelle>
        <id>92</id>
        <phone type="main">0911 737577</phone>
        <phone type="fax"></phone>
        <number/>
    </tankstelle>
</tankstellen>
```

Output:

```
{
  63 => {
          number => "",
          phone  => { fax => "0911 7592228", main => "0911 731586" },
        },
  64 => { 
          number => 64,
          phone => { fax => "", main => "0911 732011" }
        },
  91 => {
          number => "",
          phone  => { fax => "0911 732917", main => "0911 732926" },
        },
  92 => { 
          number => "",
          phone => { fax => "", main => "0911 737577" }
        },
}
```